# Alterar impressora padrão c#

Tags: c#, impressão, crystal-reports, impressora

Estou trabalhando em um solução na qual preciso alterar a impressora padrão para um impressora de etiquetas realizar a impressão e voltar para a impressora padrão anterior.

Alguém teria alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Você já tentou usar o [`SetDefaultPrinter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162971(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Vou  tentar agora, obrigado Felipe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deu certo dessa forma, segue o codigo, obrigado!

```
     using System.Drawing.Printing;
     using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    private void trocarImpressora()
    {
        ArrayList impressoras = new ArrayList(); 
        int i = 0;

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        string impressoraPadraoOriginal = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("ZDesigner GC420t (EPL)");
        imprimir();
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter(impressoraPadraoOriginal);

    }

  public static class myPrinters
    {
        [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);

    }
```